# $C^2$ function on $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

Let $T:\mathbb{R}^2 \mapsto \mathbb{R}$ be a function that its second partial derivative is continuous ($T$ is $C^2$). If $T(0,y)=0$ and $T_x(0,y)=0$ for all $y$, then show that
$$T(x,y)=x^2 S(x,y)$$
for some $S: \mathbb{R}^2 \mapsto \mathbb{R}$ which is also $C^2$.

My initial idea:

We use the Taylor expansion of $T$  about $(0,0)$ and also $T(0,0)=0$ and $T_x(0,0)=0$ to obtain

$$T(x,y)=T_y(0,0)y+\frac{1}{2}(T_{xx}(0,0)x^2+2T_{xy}(0,0)xy+T_{yy}(0,0)y^2)+U(x,y)$$
where $U$ is $C^2$ and its order is $o(x^3+y^3)$.

I have added this partial answer:

We use the above Taylor expansion.
Since $T(0,y)=0$, we have
\begin{equation}
T_{y}(0,0)y+\frac{1}{2}T_{yy}(0,0)y^2+U(0,y)=0.
\end{equation}

Since $T_x(0,y)=0$, we have
\begin{equation}
T_{xy}(0,0)y+U_x(0,y)=0.
\end{equation}
By using these two equations, we get
\begin{equation}
T(x,y)=\frac{1}{2}T_{xx}(0,0)x^2+U(x,y)-U(0,y)-U_x(0,y)x.
\end{equation}
Since $U(x,y)=U(0,y)+U_x(0,y)x+V(x,y)x^2$ where $V(x,y)x^2$ is $C^2$, one has
\begin{equation}
T(x,y)=\frac{1}{2}T_{xx}(0,0)x^2+V(x,y)x^2=x^2(\frac{1}{2}T_{xx}(0,0)+V(x,y)).
\end{equation}
Let $g(x,y)=\frac{1}{2}T_{xx}(0,0)+V(x,y)$, then $T(x,y)=x^2g(x,y)$.

My question is that how do we show that $g$ is $C^2$?

I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Where do you get the claim that $U$ is of the order you say? The error term is $o(x^2+y^2)$, is it not?

Comment: Since $T$ is $C^2$ and $U=T-\text{polynom of x and y}$, we have $U$ is $C^2$. I think you are right about the error.

Comment: It's not true. $T(x,y) = x^2\lvert x\rvert$. $S$ need not be (partially) differentiable on the line $x = 0$.

Comment: @DanielFischer I changed the problem to find SOME $C^2$ function $S$ that satisfy $T(x,y)=x^2S(x,y)$

Comment: $S$ is determined by the condition that $T(x,y) = x^2S(x,y)$ and continuity. There are $T$ that satisfy the conditions so that the corresponding $S$ is not $C^2$.

Comment: Could we add the stronger hypothesis so that we obtain $S$ is $C^2$

Comment: Your error term is still wrong. I believe you'd need $T$ to be $C^4$?

Comment: @TedShifrin I have added my partial answer. The problem now reduce to show that $g$ is $C^2$.

Comment: @DanielFischer I have added my partial answer. The problem now reduce to show that $g$ is $C^2$.

Answer (score 2):

When $f:\>{\mathbb R}\to{\mathbb R}$ is $C^2$ with $f(0)=f'(0)=0$ then we can write
$$f(x)=f(0)+\int_0^x 1\>f'(t)\ dt=(t-x)f'(t)\biggr|_{t=0}^{t=x} -\int_0^x(t-x)f''(t)\ dt=\int_0^x (x-t)f''(t)\ dt\ ,$$
and the substitution $t:=\tau\,x$ $\>(0\leq\tau\leq1)$ gives
$$f(x)=x^2\> g(x)\ ,\quad g(x):=\int_0^1(1-\tau)f''(\tau\, x)\ d\tau\ .\tag{1}$$
The function $g(x)$ $\>\left(={f(x)\over x^2}\ {\rm when}\ x\ne0\right)$ is a priori $C^2$ on ${\mathbb R}\setminus\{0\}$. According to $(1)$ it is moreover continuous on all of ${\mathbb R}$. But $g$ need not be differentiable at $0$, as  Daniel Fischer's example shows.

Comment: @Daniel Fischer: O.k., I've changed that.